# Could not save values in Nested forms using rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, relationships, model-associations

I am stuck up with building nested forms using Ruby on Rails.
I am trying to build a form which has fields from three tables(`User, Contact, Address`). User table has `address_id` and `contact_id`. When user fills the details, contact details should be saved in `contact` table and address should be saved in `address` table. Both the ids should get saved in user table along with the user details. How should I proceed?

My model,

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :user
end

class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :address
  belongs_to :contact 
end
```

My controller,

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.build_contact
    @user.build_address
  end
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, contact_attributes: [:phone], address_attributes: [:street, :city])
  end
end
```

And my view is,

```
<%= form_for(user) do |f| %>
  <% if user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
 </div>

 <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :email %>
   <%= f.text_field :email %>
 </div>

 <%= f.fields_for :contact do |c| %>
   <div class="field">
     <%= c.label :phone %>
     <%= c.text_field :phone %>
   </div>
 <% end %>

 <%= f.fields_for :address do |a| %>
   <div class="field">
     <%= a.label :street %>
     <%= a.text_field :street %>
   </div>

   <div class="field">
     <%= a.label :city %>
     <%= a.text_field :city %>
   </div>
 <% end %>

 <div class="actions">
   <%= f.submit %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Is my approach right? Kindly please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missing a couple of lines...

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :address
  belongs_to :contact
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact 
end
```

Also ensure you accept `:id` and `:_delete`

```
params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, contact_attributes: [:id, :phone, :_delete], address_attributes: [:id, :street, :city, :_delete]
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mr.Steve. It worked. Another doubt, when should I use user.contact.build ?

Comment: use `my_object.build_something` when it's a one-to-one association between `my_object` and `something` but use `my_object.somethings.build` when it's a one-to-many association between `my_object` and `something`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Mr.Steve.